# Let $M$ be a finitely generated graded $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$-module. Every component $M_s$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-rings

Let $M=\cdots \oplus M_{-1} \oplus M_0 \oplus M_1 \oplus \cdots$ be a finitely generated graded $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$-module where $\deg x_i = 1$ for all $i$.

**I would like to show that each component $M_s$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ using the fact:**

> If $R$ is Noetherian and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then $M$ is Noetherian.

---

My attempt:

Suppose some $M_s$ is not finite dimensional over $k$.

Then $M_s \oplus M_{s+1} \oplus \cdots$ is not finite dimensional over $k$.

Since $M$ is Noetherian as a $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$-module, we know $M_s \oplus M_{s+1} \oplus \cdots$ is finitely generated over $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Please put the complete statement of your question in the body of the question. The title is intended to be a title, not part of the statement of your question. As for the mathematics here, are you taking $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ as a *graded* $k$-algebra? If so, then what are the grades of the $x_i$. If not, then, I think the result is false.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks. $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is standard graded.

Comment: You mean each $x_i$ has grade $i$?

Comment: @RobArthan Standard grading usually means each $x_i$ has degree $1$.

Comment: OK. It's not a term that I was familiar with. Isn't it clear without appealing to the Noetherian property that each $M_s$ is spanned over $k$ by a finite set of elements of the form $x_Ig$, where $x_I$ is a monomial in the $x_i$ and $g$ is one of the generators of $M$?

Comment: @RobArthan I think I see. It follows since there are finitely many monomials of degree $r$ for $r \in \mathbb N$. In particular, there are $n+r-1 \choose r$ monomials of total degree $r$.

Comment: @RobArthan So $M_s$ is spanned over $k$ by all $x_I g$ where $x_I$ is a monomial of degree $s-\deg g$ and $g$ are the generators of $M$?

Comment: @user46372819 That's correct. If you want a reference, see chapter 11 of Atiyah-Macdonald (sect. Hilbert functions).